# How can I check why my Windows 10 based computer is switching off during the night?

Tags: windows-10, power

My Windows 10 computer keeps on randomly shutting down during the night. This is especially annoying since I am running some important computations on it during the night hours for my project and I have to start again every morning.

I have already disabled automatic updates and all power saving options, so it can't be that. The Windows event log just says "powered off".

The only ways to power off the machine are:

- keyboard or mouse input (I have a Logitech mouse and keyboard set that allows to switch them off at a press of a button, which I do every night), and
- the power button, which needs to be pressed for at least 5 seconds, and it cannot be pressed "by accident" as it needs a specific pressure point on it to be activated.

A power outage can be ruled out, as my Synology connected to the same power network is not affected.

How can I check what is causing the power to turn off randomly? Is there something embedded within Windows 10 that does this? Note that this is a brand new PC and I have never seen it experience any issues. It is a high-end i7-7800X based machine with loads of RAM and adequate cooling.

---

Please note that this **only** happens during the night.

Comment: It's not a standard in Windows 10, that's for sure. Maybe there is something in the BIOS settings?

Comment: Are the times consistent? Like always 1:30 am or so? Or always X hours are you stop using it?

Comment: [Read Shutdown Logs in Event Viewer in Windows | Windows 10 Tutorials](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/78335-read-shutdown-logs-event-viewer-windows.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it in Event Viewer (Open Run dialog, type eventvwr.msc and press Enter).

In the left pane of Event Viewer, double click/tap on Windows Logs to expand it, click on System to select it. You can check through the detailed logs by Date and Time.

Or you can add a filter on the logs to see only the logs for shut downs: Right click on System, and click on Filter Current Log. Under Event Sources click on the drop down menu & select USER32 from all the options. In the  field, type: 1074, then click on OK.

This should produce a list of all shutdown related events/logs. You can drill down to each logs/events' details to investigate further.

Hoping this helps.

Comment: You need to include 6006 and 6008 as well.

Comment: @DavidPostill Good point, mate.

Answer (score 1):

All I can think about is this:

1. You probably already have configured the Windows **battery settings**, so that the Computer is never put to sleep. Please be sure that you set it for both states: if the computer is plugged in AND also if it is on Battery. (Today, Microsoft Windows has many inexplicable bugs, therefore it's possible it's detecting the state wrong.)
2. Just to be sure, I would start the **Windows Memory Diagnostics** (mdsched.exe)
3. I would start a **Windows Stress Test**, e.g. [HeavyLoad, free](https://www.jam-software.com/heavyload/)). It possible that Windows is stopping by an emergency.

Kind regards, Tom

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I confirm all options in (1) are Off, (2) does not show any errors and (3) doesn't seem relevant as otherwise I would have seen issues in the Windows event log. I will run the test anyway to be sure.